# Finding x using the pythagoras theorem

Tags: problem-solving, quadratics, pythagorean-triples

$$x^2 = (x+1)^2 + (x-7)^2$$

can someone please find $x$? Also this is a quadratic equation problem solving question.

Comment: When we expand and simplify, we get a quadratic with no real roots. That's fine, but if this equation came from a geometry problem, perhaps your equation is not quite the right one.

Answer (score 5):

We don't need the Pythagorean theorem to solve this. It's just a quadratic equation.
$$x^2 = (x+1)^2 + (x-7)^2 = x^2 + 2x + 1 + x^2 - 14x + 49$$
Rearranging, we get
$$x^2 - 12x + 50 = 0$$
Now you can use the quadratic formula.

Comment: I didn't get thay rearranged equation though, i got x^2 + 16x + 48

Comment: Do you agree with the previous equation? $x^2 = x^2 + 2x + 1 + x^2 - 14x + 49$? If so, then what's $2-14$? And what is $1 + 49$?

Comment: @Lily Sounds like you had the minus in the wrong place.

Answer (score 0):

As in user$169852$'s answer
$$x^2 = (x+1)^2 + (x-7)^2 \quad
\implies x^2 - 12 x + 50 = 0$$
and the quadratic formula shows that $x$ is complex.

$$x=\dfrac{12\pm\sqrt{144-4(1)50}}{2(1)}
=
\dfrac{12\pm2i\sqrt{14}}{2} 
= 6\pm i\sqrt{14}
$$

however by the same logic

$$ x^2 = (x+1)^2 + (x+7)^2\quad  \implies 
x=-8\pm \sqrt{14}$$
and
$$x^2 = (x+1)^2 - (x - 7)^\quad \implies x\in\{4,12\}$$

I suspect that the latter is what you are looking for where

$A= x-7=5\qquad  B=x=12\qquad C=x+1=13
$
$$\implies (A,B,C)=(5,12,13)$$